# Creating a core image

Tags: disk-image

If I create an image (ie., install and do what I need to do for the image), is there a process or an application I can use to create a "spin" to roll out to a couple of computers, and is there a central management option for doing this?

Comment: I am wondering whether this question does not have a duplicate on this site. Did you search the site?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/management) Management application by ubuntu.This allows you to manage multiple computers at a time(But It is not free!!)

The other way is that you can do all the things like installation of Apps and settings etc. on one PC and then make an image of this OS and Then install that image on each PC so that you will get all PC's pre-configured!

To make such iso have a look at [Remaster ISO](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remastering_the_Install_ISO)